# Is it possible to link from current widget to my own app?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, widget

I want to combine my widget and one of my android application..

Is it possible to do that?

My plan is, once user open up my android widget, the widget will directly open up my android application?

Is there any way how?

I made some method here from my widget class:

```
public class ExampleAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
int[] appWidgetIds) {
for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

Intent intent = startActivity(new Intent("com.xxx.yyy.widget.FlamingoActivity"));
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
intent, 0);

RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
R.layout.widget1);

views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Image, pendingIntent);
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}
}
```

I tried to call the second app, by it class FlamingoActivity, but its failing.. :(

Comment: Yes..you can use appwidgetprovider class and a receiver in manifest.xml

Comment: hye kettu..please look at this link...i post the same problem..in another link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13926846/how-to-connect-an-android-widget-to-my-android-application-both-are-my-android ..maybe u might help there too , many thanks!